# oddness and evenness of sum of three square integers

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to prove that $\forall x, y ,z, v \in \mathbb{N}, x^2+y^2+z^2=v^2,$ $v$ is even **if and only if** $x,y,$ and $z$ are even. So far, after having remarked that studying the evenness of $v^2$ is  the same as studying the evenness of $v^2$ ($v^2\equiv v \mod 2$), I've been trying to separate it into four main cases : either there is none of $x,y,z$ that is even, or only one, or only two, or all three. However I find that if there are two that are odd, then their individual squares are odd, so the sum of these squares will be even, which eventually makes it so that $v^2$ is even with only $x,y$ odd. Contradicting what I have to prove. Do you have any ideea where I might have gone wrong ?

Comment: ???????  $$x=2ps$$ $$y=2ks$$ $$z=p^2+k^2-s^2$$ $$v=p^2+k^2+s^2$$

Comment: You have to show that the case $x,y$ odd with $z$ even cannot produce a square $v^2$. You may have better luck considering modulo 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A square is always congruent to $1$ or $0$ $\pmod{4}$. Hence if you assume that $x,y$ are odd they'll be congruent to $1 \pmod{4}$. Thus, if $z$ is odd we have $x^2+y^2+z^2 \equiv v^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ which is absurd.
One possible way of doing the problem is the following one :
Firstly it is easy to prove that if $x,y,z$ are even so is $v$. Now lets prove that if $v$ is even so are $x,y,z$.
Suppose that among t $x,y,z$ two of them have different parities. As we already showed that the case two odds/one even doesnt work lets consider the case where we have two even numbers and one odd. The sum of the square of two even numbers is congruent to $0 \pmod{4}$. Adding the square of the one odd number we have we find that $v^2 \equiv 1\pmod{4}$ which is absurd as we supposed $v$ even.
Hope this'll help you.
Hubert